# Newbie in the working of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am a complete novice as far as Excel is concerned. I have a spreadsheet calculating hours worked a month by rate of hourly pay. =SUM (R3:R37) in one cell calculating hours then =SUM (R38*7.83)to calculate total monthly pay in a different cell. What I would like to be able to do is combine both of these formulas to work in one cell. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: How would that final formula look like?

Comment: Did =SUM (R3:R37) in R38?

Comment: Thank you to all who offered help I now have the solution

Answer (score 0):

Put the formula from R38 in place of `R38` in the second formula:

```
=SUM(R3:R37) * 7.83
```